# How to delay/postpone hash/anchor/ID jump on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Is there a way to prevent the browser from scrolling to the ID in the url (e.g., `sitename.com/page-name/#hash`) until AFTER the entire page has loaded?

The problem with the WordPress theme I'm using is that the height of the header isn't known until after the page (or at least certain scripts) have loaded. The browser seems to be jumping to the ID before that height is known... causing part of that anchor/section to be hidden behind the header.

This problem does not occur on subsequent anchor scrolls within the same page.

I'm thinking one of the ways to solve this is to simply wait until page/window load... before the allowing the browser to scroll to the URL's hash... utilizing some sort of delay/postpone on initial hash jump.

Any ideas, using jQuery or javascript?

You can view the issue here: http://www.globalvoiceacademy.com/personalized-coaching/#commercial-coaching

Comment: I just checked your link and it appears to be working well now, would you mind sharing how you fixed this? Thanks!

Comment: Luckily the WordPress theme I was using (Divi) had a toggle built in that fixed this for me. Regardless, this may prove useful for you: https://www.askdivi.com/question/how-do-you-fix-inaccurate-behavior-of-anchor-links-when-linking-to-from-a-different-page

https://divibooster.com/fix-divi-anchor-links-not-working-correctly/

It contains an example script to do, what I assume is, the same thing.

Comment: Is there a similiar solution for Joomla CMS ? - the link provided didnt worked when I added it via a Module

Comment: I solved this problem on React using the following component. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59742690/4579271