# Is there a way to override the browser’s default scroll to hash behavior on page load?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fixed positioned header that "slides up to hide" when users scroll down similar to the one on Medium (example: https://medium.com/@sunknudsen/brute-forcing-your-very-own-vanity-onion-address-at-11-646mh-s-9a9c1fa93663#368a).

Problem is on iOS, when the browser scrolls to hash on page load (`#368a` on Medium for example), some content (`How to get your very own vanity onion address?` on Medium for example) appears under the header.

I wish to handle (override) the default scroll to hash logic (something to the likes of `event.preventDefault()`) to have more control on where to scroll, accounting for the height of the header among other things.

I am able to handle in-page navigation on React using the following logic.

```js
const scrollWithOffset = (element: HTMLElement, offset:number) => {
  let offsetTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  const elementPosition = offsetTop - offset - 20;
  window.scroll({
    top: elementPosition,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};

<HashLink
  to={props.href}
  scroll={el => scrollWithOffset(el, 104)}
  smooth
>{props.children}</HashLink>
```

Would love to apply the same logic to the default scroll to hash behavior on page load.

Comment: Doesn't the slides-up-to-hide header disappear when the browser scrolls to the element? *(Not my downvote, nor do I understand it. Maybe it's the lack of an [mcve] or other code...)*

Comment: Here is one possible way. Rename the anchor so that the # doesn't go to anywhere.
Then on load, select the anochor via id - and rename based on the #made.
Then some nice scrolling should do the trick> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @T.J.Crowder. While I process it, (for anyone who is considering downvoting this question), I am asking about how to override a browser default (if possible), not code around it. It would be very time consuming to supply a minimal reproducible example for my use case and would not provide much value.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. You want the browser to *not* scroll to the anchor on load? Perhaps a diagram or something to help make the question clear. (BTW: I strongly recommend *not* saying something will take you too much time to do. It really, really turns off the people considering spending *their* time to help you.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share how you and other feel about how I present my questions. I didn’t want to appear lazy in any way. Really sorry. I am looking for something similar to `event.preventDefault()` which could target the default scroll to hash behavior on page load. Spent over an hour browsing but didn't find anything.

Comment: (Just FYI, if there's more than one person in the comments, no one gets a notification if you don't `@` them.) No worries. I can't think of an event that you'd get for this. I wondered if `hashchange` would fire, but a quick check shows it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the precious feedback of @T.J.Crowder and to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707762/how-to-delay-postpone-hash-anchor-id-jump-on-page-load), I was able to put together a React component that overrides the browser’s default scroll to hash behavior on page load.

The behavior of this component is inspired by Medium. The page initially loads without scrolling to the element and, after a short delay (once everything has had time to load), it initiates the scroll. See https://medium.com/@sunknudsen/brute-forcing-your-very-own-vanity-onion-address-at-11-646mh-s-9a9c1fa93663#368a. I like how this delay helps contextualize the scroll.

The secret sauce is to quickly swap the `id` of the element to which the hash refers to (which disables the default scroll to hash) and to revert back to the real `id` once the DOM has had time to load.

```
export const scrollToWithOffset = (element: HTMLElement, offset:number, smooth?: boolean) => {
  let offsetTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
  let maxScrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight;
  let options: ScrollToOptions = {
    top: Math.min(offsetTop - offset, maxScrollTop),
    left: 0,
  };
  if (smooth === true) {
    options.behavior = 'smooth';
  }
  window.scroll(options);
};

interface ScrollToHashProps {}

interface ScrollToHashState {
  element?: HTMLElement;
}

export class ScrollToHash extends Component<ScrollToHashProps, ScrollToHashState> {
  constructor(props: ScrollToHashProps) {
    super(props);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }
  handleScroll() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.state.element) {
        this.state.element.id = this.state.element.id.replace('-sth', '');
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (this.state.element) {
            scrollToWithOffset(this.state.element, 0);
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    }, 0);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (window.location.hash !== '') {
      let element = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
      if (element) {
        element.id += '-sth';
        this.setState({
          element: element
        });
        if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
          window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', this.handleScroll);
        } else {
          this.handleScroll();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', this.handleScroll);
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that your slides-up-to-hide header would slide up and hide in this case as part of how it's defined.

If not, you could respond to the `DOMContentLoaded` and `window` `load` events by looking at `window.scrollY` and triggering the slide-up-to-hide behavior at that point.

If your goal is for the browser not to scroll to the element, this works for me (iOS Safari, Chrome, and Brave):

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    if (location.hash === "#foo") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

It leaves the hash in the URL, but scrolls the window to top. I don't see a flash in my experiment, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks, trying out your answer. In the meantime, would you happen to know how to handle the fact loading external web fonts affects the scroll height of hash anchors? A scroll event is triggered each time a font is loaded and applied to elements.

Comment: @sunknudsen - Ugh. I haven't had to fight that battle myself, but I *think* you can probably lock it down by setting font size in `px` and probably locking down some other font-related styles. But again, I haven't had to do it myself.

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` appeared very promising (thanks for sharing), but I am still experiencing "timing" issues on the iOS simulator where scrolls are triggered too late for `setTimeout` to run after them which opens a pandora box of latency / computing time edge cases. Will report back here if I figure out how to work around them.